# Adding a GridPane to a GridPane

Tags: user-interface, javafx, border, sudoku, gridpane

I am a beginner in using JavaFX and have to create an interactive Sudoku board for a final project. My plan was to add nine 3 by 3 GridPanes to a 3 by 3 GridPane (to make the nice looking board with outlined boxes) but can't seem to do it as I have.

Here is an excerpt from my blankBoard() creation method. board and box are predefined as global GridPane variables:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            for (int row1 = 0; row1 < 3; row1++) {
                for (int col1 = 0; col1 < 3; col1++) {
                    text = new TextField("0");
                    box = new GridPane();
                    GridPane.setConstraints(text, col1, row1); 
                    box.getChildren().addAll(text);
                }
            }
            GridPane.setConstraints(box, col, row);
            board.getChildren().addAll(box); 

        }

    }
```

All this gives me is a 3 by 3 GridPane as such: 
[GridPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxLSg.png)

Is there any other way to do this or simply add borders between just some columns and rows in a 9 by 9 GridPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are creating `9x9=81` "inner" grid panes, when you should be creating `3x3=9` of them. And then you are adding only the last of each set of 9 of them to the board. You need something like

```
GridPane board = new GridPane();


for (int blockColumn = 0; blockColumn < 3 ; blockColumn++) {
    for (int blockRow = 0; blockRow < 3; blockRow++) {

        GridPane box = new GridPane();
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, -fx-control-inner-background; -fx-background-insets: 0, 2; -fx-padding: 2;");
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
            for (int row = 0 ; row < 3; row++) {
                TextField textField = new TextField("0");
                textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 2em;");
                GridPane.setConstraints(textField, column, row);
                box.getChildren().add(textField);
            }
        }

        GridPane.setConstraints(box, blockColumn, blockRow);
        board.getChildren().add(box);

    }
}
```

The style settings just size the text fields appropriately and put a black border around each of the "blocks" (i.e. "inner grid panes").

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SudokuBoard extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane board = new GridPane();


        for (int blockColumn = 0; blockColumn < 3 ; blockColumn++) {
            for (int blockRow = 0; blockRow < 3; blockRow++) {

                GridPane box = new GridPane();
                box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, -fx-control-inner-background; -fx-background-insets: 0, 2; -fx-padding: 2;");
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                    for (int row = 0 ; row < 3; row++) {
                        TextField textField = new TextField("0");
                        textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 2em;");
                        GridPane.setConstraints(textField, column, row);
                        box.getChildren().add(textField);
                    }
                }

                GridPane.setConstraints(box, blockColumn, blockRow);
                board.getChildren().add(box);

            }
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(board));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]